# Entity Framework - What is the advantage of automatic change detection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

> When working with the EntityObject derived types or change-tracking proxy objects, the Entity Framework automatically tracks changes made to entities as they occur

What advantage does this give me? Without this my changes are still detected when I call SaveChanges and my POCO is persisted correctly.

Also, why do a lot of the online tutorials for EF explicitly change the state to modified after they make a change, what purpose does this serve?

```
context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 1):

EF tracks changes of your entities, so that when you call SaveChanges() it will know which entities to update in database, i.e. - what SQL to generate and run against db.

---

The reason for having below line, is to attach a model which is currently not being tracked and set its state to modified.

```
context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You need to do it in case if you created an instance of your Entity yourself, e.g. -

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

This will not add your customer to the DbContext and therefore its not being tracked. So you need to use context.Entry(customer) for that.

Comment: I was specifically referring to the automatic change tracking that the framework offers and what it offers over the basic snapshot tracking. As described here as 'Instant Notification'   msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696177(v=VS.103).aspx  The line changing the state to modified is used after modifying a tracked entity, which is what I don't understand. If I comment it out the entity is still updated as expected